# Find all orthogonal $3\times 3$ matrices of the form...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, orthogonality, transpose

Find all orthogonal $3\times 3$ matrices of the form

\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0\\c&d&1\\e&f&0\end{bmatrix}

---

Using the fact that $A^TA$ = $I_n$, I set that all up and ended up with the following system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a^2 + e^2 = 1\\
ab + ef = 0\\
b^2 + f^2 = 1\end{array}\right.$$

I know I can let things equal the sine and cosine of theta, but I'm not exactly sure how to write this answer down on paper. There has to be tons of possibilities, right? How many exactly?

Comment: Your equations are incorrect.

Comment: Your equations are not only incorrect, as @uniquesolution mentoined, you also need/can use more equations. You can make 9 total, one for each entry in $I_3$

Comment: consider two vectors with coordinates $(a; e)$ and $(b;f)$ so their lengths $=1$ and scalar products $=0$, so any perpendicular unit vectors satisfy these equations. How much of them we can choose?

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't see why they are incorrect?

Comment: @Lovsovs Maybe not incorrect, but not complete.. but I wonder whether is it not sufficient to add only $c=d=0$

Answer (score 5):

There are few possibilities in fact.  First of all, since $c^2+d^2+1^2=1$, $c=d=0$.

Now, you know that $a^2+b^2=1$, that $e^2+f^2=1$, and that $ab+ef=0$. This means that the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\e&f\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is orthogonal. Therefore, there is some $\theta\in\mathbb R$ such that$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\e&f\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}\text{ or that }\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\e&f\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&-\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You have 
\begin{align}
a^2+e^2=b^2+f^2&=1\\
c=d=ab+ef&=0.
\end{align}

The first equation represents the lengths of the (unit) vectors $\pmatrix{a\\e}$ and $\pmatrix{b\\f}$ and the second equation represents the scalar product of these vectors, showing that they are perpendicular.

Wihtout loss of generality, let $\pmatrix{a\\e}=\pmatrix{\cos\theta\\\sin\theta}$ for some $\theta\in\mathbb{R}.$ Then $\pmatrix{b\\f}$ can be either $\pmatrix{-\sin\theta\\\cos\theta}$ or $\pmatrix{\sin\theta\\-\cos\theta}$ (draw it if you do not see why this is).

This means that the matrix you seek is either of the two matrices

$$\pmatrix{\cos\theta & \mp\sin\theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \sin\theta  &\pm\cos\theta & 0}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $c=d=0$ and from $$a^2+b^2=1$$ $$e^2+f^2=1$$ $$2ab+2ef=0$$ you get by adding all three equations

$$(a+b)^2+(e+f)^2=2.$$

Comment: @OP
Please notice that $c=d=0$ only cause the rows need to have length $1$. Not to mistake that if the 2nd row were to be $(c,d,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ then it doesn't necessarily mean $c=d=0$